# Make php5 c++ extensions to work in php7

Tags: c++, php-7

The following code is c++ extension in php5.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(fun)
{
    char *from = NULL;
    char *to = NULL;
    int from_len, to_len;
    double oldx, oldy;
    zval *newx, *newy;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ssddzz", &from, &from_len, &to, &to_len, &oldx, &oldy, &newx, &newy) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (!newx->is_ref__gc || !newy->is_ref__gc)
    {
        printf("newx or newy isn't by ref");
        return;
    }

    convert_to_double(newx);
    convert_to_double(newy);
    func1(from, to, oldx, oldy, Z_DVAL_P(newx), Z_DVAL_P(newy));
    RETURN_LONG(result);
}
void func1(const char *from, const char *to, double oldx, double oldy, double &newx, double &newy)
{
    modify the values of newx and newy here
    ...
}
```

We can get the modified value of $x, $y using this extension like this:

```
func("abc", "sfsrf", 110.89889, 32.64534534 , $x, $y);
```

**you don't need to care about "from","to","oldx" and "oldy". They are just used to modify x$ and $y.**

These codes work well in php5. However, it dosen't work in php7. For example, is_ref__gc not exists in php7. Of course, there are many other problems.

How to modify this extension to using it in php7. And I do not want to modify the interface of fun().

Comment: Do you have an arginfo structure? If so post it. Accepting parameters by reference is done through arginfo, you don't need to handle it in the function itself (you can delete the code checking for is_ref).

Comment: Have you read the phpng upgrading guide? https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading